# DataContext returns valid data for all tables except one

Tags: c#, linq, clickonce

I've got a C# ClickOnce app where I'm getting an 'InvalidCastException; Specified Cast is not valid' when calling the stored procedure on this code;

```
        return (from o in db.usp_GetUserByName(userName)
                select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

within this section;

```
    public Database.User GetUserByName(string userName)
    {
        Security.InRole(Security.User_View);

        B.BudgetReporting.Database.BudgetReportingDataContext db = new B.BudgetReporting.Database.BudgetReportingDataContext(Functions.ConnString);
        return (from o in db.usp_GetUserByName(userName)
                select o).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I think the error is actually in the 'db' declaration in the prior section though; once the app is in debug mode and I hover on the 'db' and expand the plus,  I can see the different tables (so I assume it's connecting to the db ok, so it's not ConnString causing issues), and I can see data in all the tables EXCEPT for the 'Users' table.

When I expand out the Users section, and expand out 'Results view', it says "Expanding the results view will enumerate the IEnumerable" with a refresh icon. I click the refresh icon and I get 'base{system.SystemException}|{"Specified cast is not valid"}. So I'm guessing this is returning null which then causes the return to give the error.

This is code that was working fine but now isn't and I'm not sure why or how to keep tracking it back. I've restored a db from the same time as the code backup and it has the same Users table structure as what is in the current database.

Any clues greatly appreciated as I need to get a current version of this deployed with a new cert asap.

Stack trace:

```
[External Code] 
B.BudgetReporting.BusinessLogic.dll!B.BudgetReporting.BusinessLogic.Service.GetUserByName(string userName) Line 1663 + 0x7a bytes   C#
M.I.Beta.exe!B.BudgetReporting.Forms.Login.LoginCmd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 78 + 0x33 bytes    C#
[External Code] 
M.I.Beta.exe!B.BudgetReporting.Forms.MainMDI.checkLogin() Line 135 + 0xa bytes   C#
M.I.Beta.exe!B.BudgetReporting.Forms.MainMDI.MainMDI() Line 78 + 0x8 bytes   C#
M.I.Beta.exe!B.BudgetReporting.Program.Main() Line 22 + 0x15 bytes   C#
[External Code]
```

(NB: some slight editing to M, I and B for a bit of obfuscation)

EDIT1: GetUserByName is:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.usp_GetUserByName")]
    public ISingleResult<User> usp_GetUserByName([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="UserName", DbType="VarChar(255)")] string userName)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), userName);
        return ((ISingleResult<User>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

Comment: put  `var x= (from o in db.usp_GetUserByName(userName)
                select o).FirstOrDefault() ` what is x?

Comment: Hi JAT, that gives the same invalid cast error on the var x line (I had to add 'return x;' to the next line)

Comment: Yeah, put the breakpoint there, and put return null at the end.

Comment: k, I've got the same invalid cast error; code is now; var x = (from o in db.usp_GetUserByName(userName) select o).FirstOrDefault();
            return null;

Comment: if i put the break on the var x line; run it, x = null

Comment: To those that downvoted; it would be nice for a comment as to why you downvoted it? I'm new to c# and don't have much of an idea as to how to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue ended up being a problem in the database where a field was being referenced as an int but was actually a string causing the cast issues noted.